# How to start activity or service (Either) on bootup completed?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to find out how to run a service (Any service, may be foreground or background) when device boots. I've tried implementing broadcast receiver but it seems not to work.
Below is my full code.

**1.AndroidManifext.xml** - I made sure I included the service and broadcast receiver here. Are there any permissions I may be lacking?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.testboot">
    <!-- Example need below permission. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name="com.example.testboot.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.testboot.BootDeviceReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.example.testboot.RunAfterBootService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**2.MainActivity.java** - This is the launch class, I made it call the broadcast receiver class. Asides from that, it doesn't have anything else.

```
package com.example.testboot;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.testboot.BootDeviceReceiver");
        sendBroadcast(intent);

    }
}
```

**3.BootDeviceReceiver.java** -This is the class responsible for knowing when device has booted up (Extends Broadcast receiver)

```
package com.example.testboot;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BootDeviceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG_BOOT_BROADCAST_RECEIVER = "BOOT_BROADCAST_RECEIVER";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();

        String message = "BootDeviceReceiver onReceive, action is " + action;

        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d(TAG_BOOT_BROADCAST_RECEIVER, action);

        if(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(action))
        {
            //startServiceDirectly(context);

            startServiceByAlarm(context);
        }
    }

    /* Start RunAfterBootService service directly and invoke the service every 10 seconds. */
    private void startServiceDirectly(Context context)
    {
        try {
            while (true) {
                String message = "BootDeviceReceiver onReceive start service directly.";

                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.d(TAG_BOOT_BROADCAST_RECEIVER, message);

                // This intent is used to start background service. The same service will be invoked for each invoke in the loop.
                Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, RunAfterBootService.class);
                context.startService(startServiceIntent);

                // Current thread will sleep one second.
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Log.e(TAG_BOOT_BROADCAST_RECEIVER, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    /* Create an repeat Alarm that will invoke the background service for each execution time.
     * The interval time can be specified by your self.  */
    private void startServiceByAlarm(Context context)
    {
        // Get alarm manager.
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Create intent to invoke the background service.
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, RunAfterBootService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long intervalTime = 60*1000;

        String message = "Start service use repeat alarm. ";

        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d(TAG_BOOT_BROADCAST_RECEIVER, message);

        // Create repeat alarm.
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime, intervalTime, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

**3.RunAfterBootService.java** -  This is the service class, should be displayed after device completes booting up.

```
package com.example.testboot;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RunAfterBootService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG_BOOT_EXECUTE_SERVICE = "BOOT_BROADCAST_SERVICE";

    public RunAfterBootService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG_BOOT_EXECUTE_SERVICE, "RunAfterBootService onCreate() method.");


    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        String message = "RunAfterBootService onStartCommand() method.";

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d(TAG_BOOT_EXECUTE_SERVICE, "RunAfterBootService onStartCommand() method.");

        Intent i =  new Intent();
        i.setClass(RunAfterBootService.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

So far, when I restart my device nothing happens at all.

Comment: does the onReceive getting called ?

Comment: @Quicklearner I didnt get your question, come again clear

Comment: when you reboot phone , is the broastcast receiver working at all ? or there is something wrong in your service class ?

Comment: @Quicklearner broadcast isn't working at all. I guess there might be something wrong in my service class but it seems to be fine.

Answer (score -1):

Has your app an icon ? you must open your app one time then you can receive the boot_complete broadcast.

Comment: I am aware of that and I did it but it still didn't work

Comment: @Imnewatthis You know , each phone has their own "auto startup management" in their permission control . maybe you should try to give your app auto startup permission first.